# How to deserialize XML into an object in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read XML and deserialize it into an object in C#. I created the file with the serialization part of the ToXmlFile(Object obj, string filePath) function as given further down. I have the following XML created in the file test.xml:

```
<NYSE_Daily_Prices>
    <stock_exchange>NYSE</stock_exchange>
    <stock_symbol>ADI</stock_symbol>
    <date>2000-01-03T00:00:00</date>
    <stock_price_open>93.5</stock_price_open>
    <stock_price_high>93.87</stock_price_high>
    <stock_price_low>88</stock_price_low>
    <stock_price_close>90.19</stock_price_close>
    <stock_volume>3655600</stock_volume>
    <stock_price_adj_close>39.97</stock_price_adj_close>
  </NYSE_Daily_Prices>
  <NYSE_Daily_Prices>
    <stock_exchange>NYSE</stock_exchange>
    <stock_symbol>ADI</stock_symbol>
    <date>2000-01-04T00:00:00</date>
    <stock_price_open>89.5</stock_price_open>
    <stock_price_high>91.5</stock_price_high>
    <stock_price_low>85.56</stock_price_low>
    <stock_price_close>85.62</stock_price_close>
    <stock_volume>2533200</stock_volume>
    <stock_price_adj_close>37.95</stock_price_adj_close>
  </NYSE_Daily_Prices>
  <NYSE_Daily_Prices>
    <stock_exchange>NYSE</stock_exchange>
    <stock_symbol>ADI</stock_symbol>
    <date>2000-01-05T00:00:00</date>
    <stock_price_open>85.62</stock_price_open>
    <stock_price_high>88.25</stock_price_high>
    <stock_price_low>83.19</stock_price_low>
    <stock_price_close>86.88</stock_price_close>
    <stock_volume>3228000</stock_volume>
    <stock_price_adj_close>38.51</stock_price_adj_close>
  </NYSE_Daily_Prices>
```

Here is my object:

```
public partial class NYSE_Daily_Prices
    {
        public string stock_exchange { get; set; }
        public string stock_symbol { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
        public double stock_price_open { get; set; }
        public double stock_price_high { get; set; }
        public double stock_price_low { get; set; }
        public double stock_price_close { get; set; }
        public int stock_volume { get; set; }
        public double stock_price_adj_close { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the code to serialize/deserialize it:

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static bool NewLineOnAttributes { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to an XML string, using the specified namespaces.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToXml(object obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        Type T = obj.GetType();

        var xs = new XmlSerializer(T);
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = NewLineOnAttributes, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, ws))
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to an XML string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToXml(object obj)
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        return ToXml(obj, ns);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an object from an XML string.
    /// </summary>
    public static T FromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an object from an XML string, using the specified type name.
    /// </summary>
    public static object FromXml(string xml, string typeName)
    {
        Type T = Type.GetType(typeName);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(T);
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to an XML file.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ToXmlFile(Object obj, string filePath)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = NewLineOnAttributes, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
        ns.Add("", "");

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, ws))
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an object from an XML file.
    /// </summary>
    public static T FromXmlFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
        try
        {
            var result = FromXml<T>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("There was an error attempting to read the file " + filePath + "\n\n" + e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code I use to request the deserialization:

```
string filePath = $@"C:\Users\dmast\Documents\Upskilled\C#\C# Programming Project\MoneyBMineWpfApp\MoneyBMineWpfApp\OfflineFilesXML\{listRecentSearches.SelectedItem.ToString()}";
            NYSE_Daily_Prices result = XMLReadWrite.XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<NYSE_Daily_Prices>(filePath);
```

I keep getting the caught exception:

```
catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("There was an error attempting to read the file " + filePath + "\n\n" + e.InnerException.Message);
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: When throwing a new Exception (which should not be the base Exception class by the way) just put the actual exception as the inner exception. Now, what does the inner exception say?

Comment: The argument to `throw` includes `e.InnerException.Message` but you have not shown the output from that throw, not have you written code to show `e.Message`.

Answer (score 1):

Davide. Your code looks fine to me. I tried it locally.

Are you sure, that you provide the right path to the file?

I changed a little xml, because I assume it should have a root element. Now .xml file looks like this:

```xml
<root>
  <Prices>
    <NYSE_Daily_Prices>
      <stock_exchange>NYSE</stock_exchange>
      <stock_symbol>ADI</stock_symbol>
      <date>2000-01-03T00:00:00</date>
      <stock_price_open>93.5</stock_price_open>
      <stock_price_high>93.87</stock_price_high>
      <stock_price_low>88</stock_price_low>
      <stock_price_close>90.19</stock_price_close>
      <stock_volume>3655600</stock_volume>
      <stock_price_adj_close>39.97</stock_price_adj_close>
    </NYSE_Daily_Prices>
    <NYSE_Daily_Prices>
      <stock_exchange>NYSE</stock_exchange>
      <stock_symbol>ADI</stock_symbol>
      <date>2000-01-04T00:00:00</date>
      <stock_price_open>89.5</stock_price_open>
      <stock_price_high>91.5</stock_price_high>
      <stock_price_low>85.56</stock_price_low>
      <stock_price_close>85.62</stock_price_close>
      <stock_volume>2533200</stock_volume>
      <stock_price_adj_close>37.95</stock_price_adj_close>
    </NYSE_Daily_Prices>
    <NYSE_Daily_Prices>
      <stock_exchange>NYSE</stock_exchange>
      <stock_symbol>ADI</stock_symbol>
      <date>2000-01-05T00:00:00</date>
      <stock_price_open>85.62</stock_price_open>
      <stock_price_high>88.25</stock_price_high>
      <stock_price_low>83.19</stock_price_low>
      <stock_price_close>86.88</stock_price_close>
      <stock_volume>3228000</stock_volume>
      <stock_price_adj_close>38.51</stock_price_adj_close>
    </NYSE_Daily_Prices>
  </Prices>
</root>
```

I created 1 more class `Root`:

```cs
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlArray("Prices")]
        [XmlArrayItem("NYSE_Daily_Prices")]
        public List<NYSE_Daily_Prices> Prices { get; set; } = new List<NYSE_Daily_Prices>();
    }
```

Tested this code in console application, it works fine:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var deserializedObject = XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<Root>(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\file.xml");
        }
    }
```

[image]

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Anna, you were right about adding the root element to the xml file. I didn't add a location for the debug files. After I did so I executed the code and the path was accepted but the xml file had an inner exception due to duplicate root elements. All is working well now :)